# Unable to submit an MS app for publishing to store

Tags: csv, uwp, windows-store-apps, store

I am unable to submit my app for review in the Microsoft app store, and when I upload my csv and resources, it accepts them and says complete, but the submit button is still greyed out and unclickable, then The page reloads, and it still says incomplete.

Here's a link to the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM8Z3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV file doesn't complete everything, you need to go into your Store Listing (English) and make sure every field is filled properly. There surely is something missing in there, that is why it is incomplete.